# Bootbox Conform does not show

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootbox

Bootbox Conform not showing clicking link button.
Tried so many things, BootBox,Bootstrap and Jquery are latest installed.
It seems after clicking button, dialog is created upper right side bellow navbar because there mouse icon changes at 2 points, but conform model or dialog does not show or appear.
Here is my Html code:

```html
<table id="customers" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">Customers</th>
                <th scope="col">Membership Type</th>
                <th scope="col">Delete</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var customer in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td scope="row">@Html.ActionLink(customer.Name,"Edit","Customers",new { customer.Id },null)</td>
                    <td scope="row">@customer.MembershipType.Name</td>
                    <td scope="row"><button data-customer-id="@customer.Id" class="btn btn-link js-delete">Delete</button>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Here is my Java Script Code:

```js
@section scripts
{
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#customers .js-delete").on("click", function () {
                //e.preventDefault();
                var butten = $(this);
                bootbox.alert("Are You sure You want to Delete this Customer?")
                bootbox.confirm("Are You sure You want to Delete this Customer?", function (result) {
                        
                    if (result) {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "/api/customers/" + butten.attr("data-customer-id"),
                            method: "DELETE",
                            success: function () {
                                butten.parent("tr").remove();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
                //if (confirm("Are You sure You want to Delete this Csustomer?")) {
                    
                //}
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

Also if I use default confirm instead of bootbox confirm , everything works fine but after clicking on delete button record is deleted but page does not refresh.

Comment: see bootbox is working https://codepen.io/creativedev/pen/yEMJzm

Comment: But it's not working on my localhost project @BhumiShah

Comment: so you need to check bootbox is included properly in your project

Comment: Yeah, it was included properly , but I found the solution. Looks like Bootbox has issue with Bootstrap 4.0 and higher. I installed bootstrap 3.3.7. Now Bootbox is working fine but view is not refreshing after Agex call. record is deleted. @BhumiShah

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Looks like Bootbox has issue with Bootstrap 4.0 and higher. I installed bootstrap 3.3.7. Now Bootbox is working fine.
Any suggestion how to make it work with bootstrap 4.0 and newer?

Comment: This answer should really just be an edit to your question. Regardless, if you want BS4 support, either use the [v5x branch](https://github.com/makeusabrew/bootbox/tree/v5.x) or make the changes noted [here](https://github.com/makeusabrew/bootbox/issues/566)

Answer (score 0):

I set up a snippet to use with BS4 and jquery 3.3.1 with Bootbox 4.4.0

I removed your ajax call for simplicity, but otherwise I don't see a problem.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#customers .js-delete").on("click", function() {
    bootbox.alert("Are You sure You want to Delete this Customer?");
    bootbox.confirm("Are You sure You want to Delete this Customer?", function(result) {
      if (result) {
        console.log(result);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootbox.js/4.4.0/bootbox.min.js"></script>


<table id="customers" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Customers</th>
      <th scope="col">Membership Type</th>
      <th scope="col">Delete</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    @foreach (var customer in Model) {
    <tr>
      <td scope="row">@Html.ActionLink(customer.Name,"Edit","Customers",new { customer.Id },null)</td>
      <td scope="row">@customer.MembershipType.Name</td>
      <td scope="row"><button data-customer-id="@customer.Id" class="btn btn-link js-delete">Delete</button>
    </tr>
    }
  </tbody>
</table>
```